# Samsung Galaxy Core Prime wont turn on

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, hardware

My Samsung Galaxy Core Prime wont turn on. It goes past the Samsung logo and then goes to the metro pcs sign, but it stays there vibrating until it dies.

It charges but wont go past the metro pcs sign. I tried to restart it, and did a few hard resets. I even took the battery out. I really need help with this.

Comment: Try flashing the os again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to flash something or root it. sounds like your caught in a boot loop. if your boot loader is unlocked download the firmware for your device at http://www.sammobile.com/ and use odin for windows to flash it